# asp.net MVC dynamic configuration/ui

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic

I have plugins that implement IPlugin (IMenuPlugin, IThemePlugin, etc). I want the ability to have a each plugin provide my application with configurable properties that my application will consume and provide an edit/update UI for.

My thoughts is to have each implementation to provide a list of IEditables (defined by the interface). Each editable would provide a name of a template (EditorFor(), etc). I then want to enumerate over all of them, render the templates, then post the values back to a controller to save the values for the plugin.

Your thoughts? Is there something out there right now that is similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is something similar to what you're proposing, but I'm getting confused with the wording.

I would say that you should simply create another interface for `IPluginProperty` and then add a read-only collection of `IPluginProperty`s to `IPlugin`. The `IPluginProperty` interface could then have a property to supply the `IPropertyEditor` for the property:

```
public interface IPluginEditor
{
    // interface members
}

public interface IPluginProperty
{
    IPluginEditor Editor { get; }

    // Rest of interface members
}

public interface IPlugin
{
    IEnumerable<IPluginProperty> Properties { get; }

    // Rest of interface members
}
```

Comment: I knew how to write the code, I was just wondering if there were any libraries out there.